# .addClass() not working outside of JS Fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to all instances of the `.column` class that are in the viewport.

[This JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rH55/3/) add a class `.swoosh` to all `.column` in the viewport, but when I use the same exact js with my markup it does not add the `.swoosh` class to the `.column` in the viewport.

1. I checked if jquery is loading and it is.
2. The code is valid because it works on JS Fiddle

But for some reason, the `.column` in the viewport in [this page](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8Qdcc0hJQ3cwV0pFazA/KE%20copy.html) are not getting the class `.swoosh`.

[Here is the JS Fiddle again](http://jsfiddle.net/6rH55/3/).

[Here is the live page again](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8Qdcc0hJQ3cwV0pFazA/KE%20copy.html).

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
function isElementInViewport(el) {
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document. documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document. documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}

$.fn.checkViewportAndSetClass = function() {
  $(this).each(function(){
     if (isElementInViewport(this)) {
      $(this).addClass("swoosh");
    } 
  });
 };
$('.column').checkViewportAndSetClass();

 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    $('.column').checkViewportAndSetClass();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't including jQuery on your page. In the console: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined '. You can link to the google cdn copy by adding the following to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $(document).ready() isn't necessary in this case because the event is being bound to the window

Comment: All the instances of `.column` in the viewport are still not getting the `.swoosh` class. Check the link to my live page, I added jQuery and it loads.

Comment: I just looked again and I can see the 'swoosh' class on your elements

Comment: When I view the link in chrome and use chrome's dev tools, it says the `.swoosh` class is not added. This is what I see in dev tools: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwJVaMrY8QdcbHFDaEl4a3JIMHM/

Comment: If I load your page, scroll the scrollbar, then inspect the element (Chrome dev tools) I see this: `<div class="animated bounceInUp column swoosh" style="-moz-animation-delay:0s;-ms-animation-delay:0s;-o-animation-delay:0s;-webkit-animation-delay:0s;animation-delay:0s;">1</div>`. I'm not sure what you are expecting but the code is doing what it's supposed to do

Comment: Oh my bad, are you are expecting the first call to `checkViewportAndSetClass` to set the class? It's probably not working until you scroll the window because the elements are being animated onto the page. So I'm guessing `if (isElementInViewport(this))` will return false at the time that line of code is executed. Try waiting until the animation is done before calling `checkViewportAndSetClass`

Comment: Oh, that is a good point. Since the animation is actually moving the elements they are probably not technically in the viewport when the javascript runs. I will try postponing it until after.

Comment: No problem - glad you got it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't loading the jquery library in your live page.  Also, you should wrap your code in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {

})
```

Comment: Now, I am loading jquery, but it is still not working. Check the live page again.